# How to use Angular 2 server side rendering

Tags: angular, universal, server-side-rendering

I have developed a parser for my angular2 components which renders them in my HTML file.
So far I am able to render them in HTML as

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgSwitch, NgSwitchWhen, NgSwitchDefault,NgFor} from 'angular2/common';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',    
    template: `
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img src={{record}} class="pull-left image-responsive" style="width:50%;"> 
                    <img src={{record}} class="pull-right image-responsive" style="width:30%;">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src={{record}} class="pull-right image-responsive" style="width:100%;">
                </div>
                <br/><br/>
                <div>
                    <table class="table-responsive" style="width:100%;border-collapse:separate;border:solid #D8D8D8 2px;border-radius:5px;">
                        <tr style="background-color: grey;">
                            <th style="text-align:center;">{{record}}</th>
                            <th style="border-left:2px solid #f5821f;text-align:center;">{{record}}</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style="text-align:center;">
                            <td >&nbsp;</td>
                            <td style="border-left:2px solid #f5821f;">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <br/>
             </div>
           `
 })
export class App{
    public record;
    constructor() {       
        this.record="angular2";
    }
}
```

Then my static HTML gets generated correctly,But If I am using my component like this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgSwitch, NgSwitchWhen, NgSwitchDefault,NgFor} from 'angular2/common';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Component1} from './component_1/component_1.component';
import {Component2} from './component_2/component_2.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    directives: [Component1,Component2],
    template: `
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <component_1>loading...</component_1>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <component_2>loading...</component_2>
            </div>             
        </div>
    `
 })
export class App{
    public record;   
    constructor() {       
        this.record="angular2";
    }
}
```

Then my components are loaded in HTML correctly,but my Static HTML is not generated correctly.
See the images below:
**Components are loaded in browser**
[image: Components]

But static HTML is not generated correctly
**console window for static HTML**
[image: Console for Static HTML]

**Server.ts**

```js
import * as path from 'path';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as universal from 'angular2-universal-preview';
// Angular 2
import {App} from './app/app.component'
let app = express();
let root = path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'));

// Express View
app.engine('.ng2.html', universal.ng2engine);
app.set('views', __dirname);
app.set('view engine', 'ng2.html');

// Serve static files
app.use(express.static(root));
var i = 0;
// Routes

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index_new', {App}, function(err,html){
      console.log("------------------My HTML ---------\n"+(i++));
      console.log(html);
      console.log("------------------My HTML ----------");
      res.send(html);
  });
});

// Server
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listen on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

**index_new.ng2.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
    <link href="\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/es6-promise/dist/es6-promise.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-microtask.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/client/bundle.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading....</app>    
</body>
</html>
```

I tried the updated git Hub repository of @alexpods
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with `universal-starter-kit`
Try the https://github.com/pmachowski/angular2-starter-kit

**Pros:**

- server side rendering actually works
- web worker
- production ready
- good structure
- under active development
- modern stack (webpack, karma, protractor)
- unit & e2e tests

---

Comment: Tried this...but my node modules are not getting installed @Peter

Comment: @BhushanGadekar I can see you are on Windows. I'm on a Mac and there is no problem with node_modules. Maybe if you post the error message I could help.

Comment: `typings ERR! message Unable to resolve "github:typings/typed-es6-promise"  \n                                     
typings ERR! caused by Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/typings/typed-es6-promise/master/typings.json" \n                                                
typings ERR! caused by getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.example.com`

Comment: @BhushanGadekar Hi. It was an error in [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) library. I've updated the dependencies and moved `es6-promise` to ambient module definition. Now it should work fine. Try it out and if it doesn't work for whatever reason tell be about it.

Comment: @alexpods,its working now..but I am note sure where my static html is generated? in console its showing nothing

Comment: @alexpods I am getting this error, `    ERROR in C:\Users\Bhushan.Gadekar\Downloads\angular2-universal-starter-master\angular2-universal-starter-master\node_modules\angular2\src\mock\mock_applicat
ion_ref.d.ts
    (12,80): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.`,but application is getting loaded in browser.can you also tell me where is my static HTML generated or saved?

Comment: @BhushanGadekar Your html is inlined into bundles (dist/public/browser.js, dist/public/worker.js). index.html is generated by the server dynamically. To fix Promise problem try to add: `declare const Promise: <any>` to the `typings.d.ts`.

Comment: @alexpods i tried this,its showing too many error msgs .`    ERROR in C:\Users\Bhushan.Gadekar\Downloads\angular2-universal-starter-master\angular2-universal-starter-master\node_modules\angular2\src\mock\mock_applicat
ion_ref.d.ts
    (12,80): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.

    ERROR in C:\Users\Bhushan.Gadekar\Downloads\angular2-universal-starter-master\angular2-universal-starter-master\node_modules\angular2\src\compiler\xhr.d.ts
    (6,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'.
`

Comment: @BhushanGadekar They're all typings errors. Try to replace `  "files": [
    "typings.d.ts",
    "src/boot_browser.ts",
    "src/boot_worker.ts",
    "src/boot_worker_app.ts",
    "src/server/app.ts",
    "test/unit.spec.ts"
  ]` in `tsconfig.json` on `"exclude": ["node_modules"]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104155/discussion-between-bhushan-gadekar-and-alexpods).

Comment: angular2-starter-kit was last updated on 1 May 2016. For 2 months I'm using angular2-webpack-starter, which is a more active project at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on this [example app](https://github.com/ng-seed/universal) that I deployed recently (https://github.com/ng-seed/universal)

**Pros:**

- Server side rendering
- SCSS compilation
- Lazy/async routes
- Development/Production (AoT) compilation
- SPA/Universal modes
- TsLint/Codelyzer
- Up-to-date dependencies (Angular 4, platform-server, etc)
- Modern stack (webpack, karma, protractor)